# Use a single while loop to calculate various means

Tags: c++

I am to calculate the arithmetic mean, the geometric mean, and the harmonic mean for five numbers using a single while loop.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float a;
float g;
float h;
sum1 = 0; 
sum2 = 0; 
sum3 = 0;
n = 5;
int k;

int main()
{

    printf("Please Enter Five Integers:\n");

    while (k = 0 && k < n && ++k);
    {
        scanf("%lf", &k);
        sum1 = sum1 + k;
        sum2 = sum2 * k;
        sum3 = sum3 + (1.0 / k);
    }

    a = sum1 / n;
    g = pow(sum2, 1 / n);
    h = n / sum3;

    printf("Arithmetic mean: %.3f\n", a);
    printf("Geometric mean: %.3f\n", g);
    printf("Harmonic mean: %.3f\n", h);

    return 0;
```

Comment: `k` is a counter and read value at the same time?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: replace `while (k = 0 && k < n && ++k);` with `for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)`

Comment: The question is, what am I doing wrong? I only get 0's for all the values.

Comment: Also, my assignment states to use exactly one while loop.

Comment: I guess passing `int*` to `%lf` of `scanf()` is not good. It is undefined behavior in C.

Comment: What is types of `sum1`, `sum2`, `sum3` and `n`?

Comment: `int count = 0; while (count < 5) { existing loop body; count ++; }`

Comment: `while (k = 0 && k < n && ++k);` <-- bad place for a semicolon.

Comment: @undermind No, because the loop and block containing reading is separated statements. Moreover, the loop won't taken because `k = 0` is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C program has several issues.

You don't declare all the variables you are using, for example, and there's no need for them to be global.

Your initial value for sum2 (0) is wrong, it will never update because you repetedly multiply k times 0.

Then in `pow(..., 1 / n)` the 1/n is an integer division, so you are elevating to 0.

Your loop and its condition must be modified. Try this, I used double, instead of integers and float, but it depends on your assignment:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX 80

int main()
{
    double a, g, h, k;
    double sum = 0, prod = 1, sum_inv = 0;
    const int n = 5;
    int i = 0;

    printf("Please, enter five numbers:\n");

    char buffer[MAX];
    while ( i < n ) {
        fgets(buffer, MAX, stdin);
        if ( sscanf(buffer, "%lf", &k) != 1 ) {
            printf("Wrong format, floating point number expected\n");
            continue;
        }
        if ( k == 0.0 ) {
            printf("You should enter non zero numbers\n");
            continue;
        }
        ++i;
        sum += k;
        prod *= k;
        sum_inv += (1.0 / k);
    }

    a = sum / n;
    g = pow(prod, 1.0 / n);
    h = n / sum_inv;

    printf("Arithmetic mean: %.3f\n", a);
    printf("Geometric mean: %.3f\n", g);
    printf("Harmonic mean: %.3f\n", h);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `continue;` without consuming "wrong" input after `scanf()` fails may lead to infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me tremendously.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies if this is brutal, but simply saying there are multiple issues and proceeding to correct them without explaining why they are issues or what was done to correct them doesn't make for a very good answer. It makes for homework cut-and-paste.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

This is actually a bad idea. Those security warnings often tell you you're taking unnecessary risks. They are annoying, but often they are right.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
```

These should be `<cstdio>` and `<cmath>`. Better still, don't use cstdio. Use the C++ equivalents.

```
float a;
float g;
float h;
sum1 = 0; 
sum2 = 0; 
sum3 = 0;
n = 5;
```

The preceding 4 variables do not have data types. All variables must have a type.

Further initializing sum2 to zero when it will be used to gather a product is a bad idea. 0 will result.

```
int k;
```

None of these variables need to be global and all of the variable names are non-descriptive. In a program this size, that's not horrible, but in a large program with dozens or thousands of variables, being able to read from the variable name what it does and what it contains is worth it's weight in gold.

```
int main()
{

    printf("Please Enter Five Integers:\n");

    while (k = 0 && k < n && ++k);
```

The `;` is a bad mistake here. `;` ends the instruction. It separates the loop from it's body, so you get a while the loops but does nothing else.

But let's look at the loop conditions shall we?

```
k = 0
```

this is the same as

```
k = 0
if (k)
```

Which is always false since `k` is 0.  This exits the loop right here.

```
k < n
```

Which it always is because of `k = 0`. `k` is 0. A moot point because this never gets tested.

```
++k
```

is always true because at this point `k` will always be 1.

This screams read the textbook more closely because you missed quite a bit.

```
    {
        scanf("%lf", &k);
```

This line reads a floating point number into an integer. Not a good idea. The results will be bizarre at best.

In addition, the return code from `scanf` is untested so you have no way to tell whether or not `scanf` successfully read a value.

And this question is tagged C++. Why use C?

```
        sum1 = sum1 + k;
        sum2 = sum2 * k;
        sum3 = sum3 + (1.0 / k);
```

That all looks good to me, other than being really bad, non-descriptive names.

```
    }

    a = sum1 / n;
```

Syntactically and logically sound.

```
    g = pow(sum2, 1 / n);
```

`1 / n` will be performed entirely in integer arithmetic and certainly result in a fraction. Integers can't do fractions, so this will result in 0. Any number to the power of 0 is one.

```
    h = n / sum3;
```

Looks good.

```
    printf("Arithmetic mean: %.3f\n", a);
    printf("Geometric mean: %.3f\n", g);
    printf("Harmonic mean: %.3f\n", h);
```

Again, using C in C++. `printf` has it's uses, even in C++, and frankly this is one of those cases where I might use it (but with caution because there is a performance hit) because the C++ equivalent `std::cout << "Arithmetic mean: " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << a << '\n';` is brutally verbose.

```
    return 0;
}
```

Revising this for C++

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>


int main()
{
    // discarded a, g, and h. Renamed the rest for easier reading
    float sum = 0;
    float product = 1;
    float invSum = 0;
    constexpr int MAX = 5;
    int input;

    std::cout <<"Please Enter Five Integers:" << std::endl;
    int count = 0;
    while (count < MAX)
    {
        if (std::cin >> input)
        { // read a good, or at least not horrible, number
          // this will not handle the problem of "123abc" as input. "123" will be
          // accepted and "abc" will be seen as a second token and rejected.
          // proper handling of this is a question unto itself and has been asked 
          // hundreds of times.
            sum += input;
            product *= input;
            invSum += (1.0 / input);
            count++;
        }
        else
        { // clean up and ask for new input
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            std::cout <<"Bogus integer. Input again: " << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Arithmetic mean: " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << sum / MAX << '\n';
    std::cout << "Geometric mean: " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << pow(product, (1.0 / MAX))  << '\n';
    std::cout << "Harmonic mean: " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << MAX / invSum << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1. Well explained. Only one minor note: I think it would never reach ++k. BTW I simply assumed the c++ tag was wrong.

Comment: Thanks, and you're right. It can't reach `++k` or `k < n` because of the `k = 0`. I covered all of them because they all fail to do what is intended in slightly different ways. You covered the C way, so I hit it from the C++ direction.